# display dialog box before login ubuntu 16.04 LTS server

Tags: boot, command-line, server, login, startup

Hi i am trying to customize the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS what i want to achieve is i want to display the dialog box with ip address and the button 'ok' before login to terminal means first it display the dialog box then when i press 'ok' button then it show the terminal . I try this command

```
dialog --msgbox "Hello, your ip is $ifconfig"
```

then i add this in .bashrc but it won't display it before login it directly boot and move to terminal screen . I hope you get my question any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You will not know the username (variable ```$USER```) before logging in.

Comment: its fine np i just want to dispaly the dialog box before login with any text or ip.

Comment: If you want only to display the message, you can use this solution: https://superuser.com/questions/290294/how-to-display-a-message-before-login . However, it only displays text; there is no option of waiting to press the 'ok' button.

Comment: Hi! Can you please clarify what display manager you are using (if any)?

Comment: i am using dialog